# Grinding clutch

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, acura, integra

i have a 00' integra and i think the original clutch is still in it, 180,000km. when i have the car in gear there is a faint grinding sound. the same thing happens only more so when i engage the clutch. the only way i can stop it while driving is by double clutching and when im in neutral it stops the grinding; however if i put it in neutral and leave the clutch engaged it continues to grind, wondering if i just need a new clutch or if it could be something else.

Comment: It sounds to me likely that you have a noisy release bearing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a transmission, not a clutch problem. The only time the clutch itself can make any noise is during engagement/disengagement. You may hear noise if the clutch is slipping, but it wouldn't be slipping (in most *every* circumstance) in neutral. Since it's still making noise when engaged, yet not when disengaged, the only other place to look is the transmission.

The term "grinding" is a broad term. I have no clue why double clutching would make it stop or make it any better.

Comment: so lets say im in 3rd gear. i can faintly hear the grinding, if i engage the clutch, the grinding gets a little lounder (could just be because the engine is making less noise) if i leave the clutch engaged and put the car in neutral the noise stays. but if i let go of the clutch with it in neutral the noise goes away.

Comment: what i meant by double clutching is that if i double clutch from 3rd to 4th the only time it isnt making the noise is while it is in neutral with the clutch disengaged

Comment: So we are on the same footing: Pressed clutch pedal = disengaged clutch; Released clutch pedal = engaged clutch. Your descriptions seem to be mixing this up. If I understand what you're saying, it still leads me back to the transmission having issues.

Comment: okay yeah i was explaining it as if engaging the clutch was pressing it in, my bad

Comment: There ya go! ^^^Adds up now. Throwout bearing.